# File Upload Controls using Razor in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor

Is there a way to define the file upload controls using a Razor helper in ASP.NET MVC3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There isn't an html helper for file inputs, but what is wrong with just doing

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) {
    <input type='file' name='blah' id='blah' />
}
```

Comment: No client side validation out of the box.

Comment: Beats nothing out of the box

Comment: `<input type='file' name='FilePath' id='FilePath'  />` FilePath is given as the   model property name,So you can use it like any other control.

Answer (score 4):

There is a FileUpload class in Microsoft.Web.Helpers... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers.fileupload(v=vs.99).aspx

The best/only way I've found to get it is by using NuGet in VisualStudio.  Search for package "microsoft-web-helpers" in the online repository.  There is one problem I encountered, however.  One of the package's dependencies is Facebook.Helper, which it will install at the same time. It will place a file called "Facebook???.cshtml" (forgot the exact name) in your project's AppCode directory.  The problem is that the Facebook???.cshtml had some WebMatrix dependencies that I didn't have and didn't want to install.  Simply deleting the Facebook.cshtml file (which I wasn't going to use, anyway) seemed to resolve the issue.  After that, I was able to compile and debug as usual and use the FileUpload class.

Here's a tutorial I found that utilizes it:

http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/using-mvc3-razor-helpers-and-jcrop-to-upload-and-crop-images/

Comment: That tutorial is OK, but it doesn't explain clearly what code goes where. I'd suggest this one instead since it's just about file uploading (not resizing images as well): http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Creating-a-multiple-file-upload-form-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Comment: Pauk's link gave way to bitrot. Here's a [Wayback link](http://web.archive.org/web/20150712030605/http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk:80/mygreatdiscovery/post/Creating-a-multiple-file-upload-form-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

USING RAZOR

```
@*requieres installing Asp helpers / you can do it her from NuGet or logging som admin in packages*@
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
@{
    var fileName = "";
    if (IsPost) {
        var fileSavePath = "";
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" +
          fileName);
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    }
}

      @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false, 
        includeFormTag:false,
        name: "Upload1",
        uploadText:"Upload")

    @if (IsPost) {
        <span>File uploaded!</span><br/>
    }
```

Comment: None of this `IsPost` login should be in the view, it all belongs in the controller, ideally split between two methods, one of which having the `[HttpPost]` decorator.