# Form Collection is empty When I use enctype for file uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an app in asp.net in which I am going to upload file but when I use enctype = "multipart/form-data" Form collection is empty and when I do not use enctype, form collection has name of uploading file but Request.Files.count = 0. I want to get file upload and also the name of uploading file in form collection. Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check out with following code:

Add the encoding type in form of view by following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees", FormMethod.Post,new{ enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{   
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Resume, new { type = "file" })

    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
@Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

Add following code in your respective action of your controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel viewModel)
{
       if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                string pathFile = string.Empty;
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string path = string.Empty;
                    string fileName = string.Empty;
                    string fullPath = string.Empty;
                    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "directory where you want to upload file";//here give the directory where you want to save your file
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))//if path do not exit
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "directory_name/");//if given directory dont exist, it creates with give directory name
                    }
                    fileName = Request.Files[file].FileName;

                    fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {

                        if (fileName != null && fileName.Trim().Length > 0)
                        {
                            Request.Files[file].SaveAs(fullPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I asssumed path will be inside the directory of basedirectory....You can give your own path where you desire to save file

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someaction", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

Notice that the file input must have a `name` that will be used later in the controller action to fetch the file. The fact that you are getting Request.File.Count = 0 is a very strong indication that you didn't provide a name to your input field.

and the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), filename);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }
    return View();
}
```

and if you wanted to use the FormCollection (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var file = Request.Files["file"];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), filename);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }
    return View();
}
```

You may also checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What about to use :

```
@Microsoft.Web.Helpers.FileUpload.GetHtml("File", 1, false, false, null, null)
```

Then in your controller :

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    Request.Files[0]; //Check this out !
}
```

More info :

StackOverFlow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5060318

Tallan Blog : http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/using-mvc3-razor-helpers-and-jcrop-to-upload-and-crop-images/